# Array Formulas for non-numerical data?

Tags: google-sheets

I am working with Google sheets and looking to make a formula that will auto-apply to new rows that are added.  All the existing answers I have found show how an array formula can do this with mathematical operations, I cannot figure out how to make this work with my formula, which goes in row E:

> =RIGHT(D1:D,LEN(D1:D)-44)

If there is no way to auto-insert this into a new row in Google Sheets itself, is there a Google Script I could use to detect new rows and put this formula in the proper column?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you just need to wrap your formula with `ArrayFormula()`.

Comment: @AdamL When I do put =ARRAYFORMULA(=RIGHT(D1:D,LEN(D1:D)-44)), the cell gives me a formula parse error.  From the other reading I've done on Array formulas, they only seem to work with numerical formulas and not with one meant to change the data.

Comment: The array formula will work fine here. Just omit the second equals sign.

Comment: @AdamL Thanks - the first time I tried I got a #REF error saying the formula would overwrite data in cell E2 (which I had cleared of data), so I had to just delete the current column and put in a new one to get it to work.  But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about "row E:" but enter your formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.